# Iterate through lists with varying elements

Tags: python

I have 3 lists containing a Bitcoin transaction inputs, outputs, and values(price). Depending on the transaction, the Inputs or outputs may contain one or more elements(BTC addresses) eg in one transaction the outputs list may have 2 elements with one corresponding addresses.

I would like to write these to a file in such format:

```
TransactionID, Sender(input), Recipient(output), value
```

Transactions involving multiple senders and multiple receivers should be by multiple lines with the same transaction id.

I have tried using standard for loops and zip_longest(see below) with no avail and have been stuck on this problem for a while so any help would be greatly appreciated. The lists below are an example transaction and can vary as mentioned.

```
    inputs = ['1Pr75FNvtoWHeocNfc4zTQCfK5kMVakWcn']
    outputs = ['1EXoDusjGwvnjZUyKkxZ4UHEf77z6A5S4P', 
   '1Pr75FNvtoWHeocNfc4zTQCfK5kMVakWcn', 
   '14Vx2RDjFjCLXCxrrqKEr6DsCwX5RZX7Jj', 
   '1Pr75FNvtoWHeocNfc4zTQCfK5kMVakWcn']

    values = ['0.00000546', '0.00000671', '0.00001246', '0.00000146']


    if len(outputs) > len(inputs):
        for x, y in zip_longest(outputs, inputs, values): 
            file.write(transID, x y, z)


    elif len(inputs) > len(outputs):
        for x, y z in zip_longest(inputs, outputs, values): 
            file.write(transID, x, y , z)
```

Comment: How are you going to split multiple parties into pairs - all combinations? What about the sums?

Comment: Sorry, can you explain? I'm not quite sure what you are asking.

Comment: Did I understood correctly that: a) inputs-outputs - one of them has length==1?, b) `len(values)` **must be** equal to length of longest of inputs/outputs?, c) inputs,outputs,values - are data for only 1 transaction?

Comment: Just give an example of what you expect as output in the case of many inputs and many outputs.

Comment: Inputs or outputs could have a length == 1 or  > 1, everything else you assumed is correct. Would your answer still work in this situation?

Comment: Is it correct when `len(inputs)==len(outputs)==1` ?

Comment: Not quite, the output is: Output, Input, Price. Instead of Input, Output, Price. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that I understood the problem correctly:

```
inputs = ['1Pr75FNvtoWHeocNfc4zTQCfK5kMVakWcn']
outputs = ['1EXoDusjGwvnjZUyKkxZ4UHEf77z6A5S4P', 
   '1Pr75FNvtoWHeocNfc4zTQCfK5kMVakWcn', 
   '14Vx2RDjFjCLXCxrrqKEr6DsCwX5RZX7Jj', 
   '1Pr75FNvtoWHeocNfc4zTQCfK5kMVakWcn']

values = ['0.00000546', '0.00000671', '0.00001246', '0.00000146']

if len(inputs)< len(outputs):
    root, branches = inputs[0], outputs
else:
    root, branches = outputs[0], inputs

transaction = [(root, branch,value) for branch,value in zip(branches, values)]

print(transaction)
```